# Problem with state management and Core Data

Tags: swiftui

I'm fairly new to Swift and Core Data. I’m having a problem resolving a state issue in a new project of mine.

I have a parent view (CategoryView)that includes a context menu item to allow editing of certain category properties (EditCategoryView). When the EditCategoryView sheet is presented and an edit to a category property is made, the CategoriesView updates correctly when the sheet is dismissed. Works fine.

There is a navigation link off of CategoriesView (ItemsView) that also includes a context menu to allow editing of certain item properties (EditItemView). Unlike the prior example, when the EditItemView sheet is presented and an edit is made to an item property, the ItemsView does not update when the sheet is dismissed. The old item property still displays. If I navigate back to CategoriesView and then return to ItemsView, the updated item property displays correctly.

I’m stumped and clearly don’t understand how state is managed in a CoreData environment. My code for the 2 views seems to be similar, yet they are behaving distinctly different. I wonder if the problem relates to the difference in the structures used in the 2 ForEach lines. That is, in CategoriesView I'm looping on the results of a Fetch and in EventsView I'm looping on the results of a computed value.

Any suggestions? thanks in advance for any guidance.

I created a simple example project that demonstrates the problem. To reproduce:

- tap on Load Sample Data
- choose a Category
- tap and hold an Item to bring up context menu
- choose Edit and change the name of the item
- you’ll note when sheet dismisses the updated name is not reflected
- return to Category list and then select the item again to see the updated name

https://github.com/jayelevy/CoreDataState

edit to include the code for the minimal example referenced in the repo

```
xcdatamodeld
2 Entities
Category
   Attribute: name: String
   Relationships: items, destination: Item (many-to-one)
Item
   Attribute: name: String
   Relationships: category, destination: Category (to one)
```

```swift
@main
struct CoreDataStateApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var dataController: DataController
    
    init() {
        let dataController = DataController()
        _dataController = StateObject(wrappedValue: dataController)
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            CategoriesView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
                .environmentObject(dataController)
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification), perform: save)
        }
    }
    
    func save(_ note: Notification) {
        dataController.save()
    }
}
```

```swift
struct CategoriesView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)])
    var categories: FetchedResults<Category>
   
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(categories) { category in
                        NavigationLink {
                            ItemsView(category: category)
                        } label : {
                            Text(category.categoryName)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("My Categories")
            
            .toolbar {
             
                ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                    Button {
                        dataController.deleteAll()
                        try? dataController.createSampleData()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Load Sample Data")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

problem occurs with the following view. When an item is edited in EditItemView, the updated property (name) does not display when returning to ItemsView from the sheet.

If you return to CategoryView and then return to ItemsView, the correct property name is displayed.

```swift
struct ItemsView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var category: Category
    
    @State private var isEditingItem = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(category.categoryItems) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        //
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.itemName)
                    }
                    .contextMenu {
                        
                        Button {
                            isEditingItem.toggle()
                        } label: {
                            Label("Edit Item", systemImage: "pencil")
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isEditingItem) {
                        EditItemView(item: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(category.categoryName)
    }
    
}
```

```swift
struct EditItemView: View {
    
    var item: Item
    
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    @State private var itemName: String

    init(item: Item) {
        //        _item = ObservedObject(initialValue: item)
        self.item = item
        _itemName = State(initialValue: item.itemName)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        TextField("Item Name", text: $itemName)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Edit Item")
            
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                    // add any needed cancel logic
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button {
                        saveItem()
                        dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Update")
                    }
                    .disabled(itemName.isEmpty)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveItem() {
        item.name = itemName
        dataController.save()
    }
}
```

```swift
extension Category {
    
    var categoryName: String {
        name ?? "New Category"
    }
    
   var categoryItems: [Item] {
        items?.allObjects as? [Item] ?? []
    }

extension Item {
    
    var itemName: String {
        name ?? "New Item"
    }
    
}

extension Binding {
    func onChange(_ handler: @escaping () -> Void) -> Binding<Value> {
        Binding(
            get: { self.wrappedValue },
            set: { newValue in
                self.wrappedValue = newValue
                handler()
            }
        )
    }
}
```

```swift
class DataController: ObservableObject {
    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer
    
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Model")
        
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Fatal error loading store: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    static var preview: DataController = {
        let dataController = DataController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = dataController.container.viewContext
        
        do {
            try dataController.createSampleData()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Fatal error creating preview: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return dataController
    }()
    
    
    func createSampleData() throws {
        let viewContext = container.viewContext
        
        for i in 1...4 {
            let category = Category(context: viewContext)
            category.name = "Category \(i)"
            category.items = []
            
            for j in 1...5 {
                let item = Item(context: viewContext)
                item.name = "Item \(j)"
                item.category = category
            }
        }
        try viewContext.save()
    }
    
    func save() {
        if container.viewContext.hasChanges {
            try? container.viewContext.save()
        }
    }
    
    func delete(_ object: NSManagedObject) {
        container.viewContext.delete(object)
    }
    
    func deleteAll() {
        
        let fetchRequest1: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Item.fetchRequest()
        let batchDeleteRequest1 = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest1)
        _ = try? container.viewContext.execute(batchDeleteRequest1)
        
        let fetchRequest2: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Category.fetchRequest()
        let batchDeleteRequest2 = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest2)
        _ = try? container.viewContext.execute(batchDeleteRequest2)
    }
    
    func count<T>(for fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T>) -> Int {
        (try? container.viewContext.count(for: fetchRequest)) ?? 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. The example should be included as code in the question and not a link to your repo. Links break over time.

Comment: it almost feels like I see this same question every time.

Comment: All CoreData objects should be wrapped in an `@ObservedObject` to see the changes. Even the ones in the relationships, create subviews and pass the object so this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

`ItemsView` needs its own `@FetchRequest` for `CategoryItem` with a predicate where `category = %@`.

Also, instead of passing your `DataController` object around just put your helper methods in an extension of `NSManagedObjectContext`. Then you can change `DataController` back to the struct it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there are other opportunities to improve my code (obviously, still learning), per other posts. However, the resolution was quite simple.

Modified saveItem in EditItemView to include objectWillChange.send()

```
  func saveItem() {
        item.name = itemName
        item.category = itemCategory
        item.category?.objectWillChange.send()
        dataController.save()
    }
```